# Text.XML.Cursor - Lost in the types

Tags: xml, haskell

For this problem, I will paste a sample stanza from the xml file I am working with, then discuss what I am trying to do with it.

I have an xml file with stanzas that look like this:

```
<mb model="460" rev="dba">
        <dmiblock block="Base Board Information">
                <dmiattr name="Manufacturer" value="MSI"/>
                <dmiattr name="Product Name" value="H61M-P25 (MS-7680)"/>
        </dmiblock>
        <dmiblock block="Memory Device">
                <dmiattr name="Bank Locator" value="A1_BANK0"/>
                <dmiattr name="Size" value="4096 MB"/>
        </dmiblock>
        <dmiblock block="Memory Device">
                <dmiattr name="Bank Locator" value="A1_BANK1"/>
                <dmiattr name="Size" value="No Module Installed"/>
        </dmiblock>
        <dmiblock block="Memory Device">
                <dmiattr name="Bank Locator" value="A1_BANK2"/>
                <dmiattr name="Size" value="No Module Installed"/>
        </dmiblock>
        <dmiblock block="Memory Device">
                <dmiattr name="Bank Locator" value="A1_BANK3"/>
                <dmiattr name="Size" value="No Module Installed"/>
        </dmiblock>

        <cpublock number="0">
                <cpuattr name="model name" value="Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G850 @ 2.90GHz"/>
        </cpublock>
        <cpublock number="1">
                <cpuattr name="model name" value="Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G850 @ 2.90GHz"/>
        </cpublock>
        <pciblock block="NIC">
                <pciattr string="Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection" number="2" />
        </pciblock>
        <blockblock block="model">
                <blockattr value="8GB SATA SSD T 3" number="1" />
                <blockattr value="WDC WD5003ABYX-0" number="1" />
        </blockblock>
</mb>
```

I am trying to find stanzas based on the value of the attributes `model` from the `mb` `node` and the `value` attribute from the second element in the first child of the `mb` `node`. So, in the stanza above, I would be trying to match against `model="460"` and `value="H61M-P25 (MS-7680)"`. Having matched against that, I'd want to put `rev="dba"` in a list and continue searching for other stanzas with the same attributes in other `mb` `nodes`.

I haven't gotten very far at all, I keep getting tripped on the types. I am using [this](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/xml) to work from.

```
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor
import qualified Data.Text as T


getProfiles :: AdviseConf -> IO () -- AdviseResult
getProfiles  (AdviseConf model mb) = do
   doc <- Text.XML.readFile def xmlFile
   let cursor = fromDocument doc
   _ <- Prelude.writeFile "test.txt" $
        show                         $
        T.concat                     $
        cursor                       $//
        element "mb"                 >=>
        attributeIs "model" "460"    >=>
        element "dmiattr"            >=>
        attributeIs "value" "H61M-P25 (MS-7680)" 
        &// content
```

I know the final function `content` is wrong, but I dont know which would be right. I'm trying to capture all the `rev` attributes from the nodes that match.

So, when I play with the above, I either end up with an empty list, junk characters, or a type error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think you're looking for the `attribute` function.
2. By using `>=> element "dmiattr"` you're saying "the current element's name is `dmiattr`'. I think you might mean `&/ element "dmiattr"`. But since you want the @rev attribute of the parent, you probably need to use the `check` function instead.