# XML Child/Sibling Parsing

Tags: xml, haskell, yesod

I'm continuing the problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187807/text-xml-cursor-lost-in-the-types) question. The task is to search through the `mb` nodes for 
the `model` `attribute` with a certain value, then filter out the ones that did not
match the `value` `attribute` in the `dmiattr` element. Once filtered, I need to capture a list of values from the `rev` `attribute`. I've made some progress. I am able to match against the `model` `attribute` and capture the values of the `rev` attribute.

But I am having difficulty drilling down to the child `dmiattr`. I think I have almost all the correct functions, perhaps not the correct combinators. And maybe the logic of my code is wonky too. I'm not sure where it goes wrong. Feedback approciated.

```
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor
import qualified Data.Text as T



getProfiles :: AdviseConf -> IO () -- AdviseResult
getProfiles  (AdviseConf model mb) = do
   doc <- Text.XML.readFile def xmlFile
   let cursor = fromDocument doc
   _ <- Prelude.writeFile "test.txt" $
        show                         $
        cursor                       $//
        check findNode               &.// -- &//
        attributeIs "model" "460"    &.//
        check findMB                 &.//
        followingSibling             &.//
        attributeIs "value" "GF615M-P33  (MS-7597)" &.//
        attribute "rev"
   return ()

findNode :: Cursor -> Bool
findNode c = case (attribute "rev" c) of
              []  -> False
              otherwise -> True

findMB :: Cursor -> Bool
findMB c = case ( attribute "value"  c) of
            [] -> False
            otherwise -> True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't follow all the details in your code (what's the purpose of `followingSibling`, for example?). But I think this gets you pretty close to what you were looking for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor

main = do
   doc <- Text.XML.readFile def "test.xml"
   let cursor = fromDocument doc
   print $
        cursor                       $//
        hasAttribute "rev"           >=>
        attributeIs "model" "460"    &.//
        check (\c -> c $// element "dmiattr"
                       >=> attributeIs "value" "GF615M-P33  (MS-7597)") >=>
        attribute "rev"
```

Notice that the argument to the `check` function returns a list. If that list is empty, it's treated the same as `False`, and therefore the check fails.

Comment: My reasoning comes from not really understanding what some of these functions do. I thought that since the `<dmiattr` element I was looking for was the second child, I had to use `followingSibling` to get to it. I'll try out your code, and I imagine if it's not exactly what I need I can play around with it. Thanks again.